# Ruby Rails 3.2 mailer in production throw error no such file to load sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, actionmailer, premailer

I'm using JRuby 1.7.3 Rails 3.2.13 hosted on GlassFish 3.1. I'm using premailer-rails to inline the css to send email. Work ok in development. But production gives error: "LoadError (no such file to load -- sass"
  (in ../apps/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_override.css.scss)).

```
layouts/mailer.html.haml
    = stylesheet_link_tag "mail"
    %style{:type => "text/css"}


configuration/application.rb
    config.assets.precompile += ['mail.css']

app/assets/stylesheets/mail.css.scss
    h2.mail {
        color: #2871a8;
    }
app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_override.css.scss
    @import "twitter/bootstrap";

Gemfile
    group :assets do
        gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
        gem 'sass-rails'
        gem 'coffee-rails'
        gem 'therubyrhino'
        gem 'uglifier'
    end
    gem 'premailer-rails'
```

I can't figure out why it's failing in production. If I use the mailer layout which only includes mail.css, I don't know why it would try to also include bootstrap_and_override.css and throw that error. Any idea?

Comment: Found the root cause. Needs to put premailer-rails in the assets group so asset precompile will convert the inline css.